# How to set different IP address for client and server in socket programming

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I am creating a client server protocol in python. I intend to run the client and server on the same computer during testing. Is it possible to assign a different IP address to the server and then another IP address to the client?

Comment: There are some rather convoluted OS dependent ways to assign multiple IP addresses to a single NIC, but that seems like a lot of work. So, why do you want to do that? Clients don't typically care what their IP addresses are.

Comment: If this is for testing, a common solution is to create a virtual machine for one of them. It will have a virtual NIC and its own IP address.